# Hide a table or td with no class or id

Tags: html, css

I don't have access to the HTML to add a id to this td , i have it hidden in FF and Chrome, but IE10 will not hide it using either of the css calls i added

HTML

```
<td width="280" height="100%" vAlign="top" sizzle-1367337785481="[object Object]">
```

CSS i'm using in FF and Chrome to hide , but not working in IE10

```
td[width='280'] { display:none!important;height:0!important;visibility:hidden!important }
td[height='100%'] { display:none!important;height:0!important;visibility:hidden!important }
```

any suggestions on how to hide this in IE ?

[image]

Comment: Does the td have a consistent position wrt its siblings? If so you could use the nth-child selector.

Comment: Can you just increase the specificity of the selector?

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam - Did you even read the question? jQuery isn't needed here. The OP needs to select it and already knows how to hide it.

Comment: Can we see the parent `<tr>`, you may be able to play off it?

Comment: Try with "nth-child" it's supported by IE9+.

Comment: Show us some more of the surrounding markup.

Comment: add screen shot of IE developer, td i want removed it shaded in purple

Comment: when using td[colspan="2"] {display:none;} , it works fine in IE , but when using a height or width attribute, will not work

Comment: Probably because `height` and `width` are not listed as valid attributes on a `td` in HTML5 ([see here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/td)).

Comment: This link might help you, it solved the asker's problem. http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/95311-fixed-cell-width-table-does-not-work-ie . (for the most relevant part, scroll to the last 2 posts; it involves `style="table-layout: fixed"`)

Comment: @Tyblitz, i dont see relevance to the link and my question, thanks